# C++17 Infer return type of lambda based visitor

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, variadic-templates, visitor-pattern

Here's the lambda overload based visitor given in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit:

```
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;
std::visit(overloaded {
  [](auto arg) { std::cout << arg << ' '; },
  [](double arg) { std::cout << std::fixed << arg << ' '; },
  [](const std::string& arg) { std::cout << std::quoted(arg) << ' '; },
}, v);
```

where `v` is a `variant` and all its types must have implemented lambdas.

**I want to add a function to `overloaded` that has the same return type as all lambdas** (which is then the return type of `visit(overloaded{...}, v)`).
Something similar to:

```
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts...
{
  using Ts::operator()...;

  common_type_t<decltype(declval<Ts>())...> test() const { return {}; }
};
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;
auto r = std::visit(overloaded {
  [](auto arg) { return 1; },
  [](double arg) { return 2; },
  [](const std::string& arg) { return 3; },
}, v);
```

Here something goes wrong and `common_type<_Tp...>::type` doesn't exist.
I thought about using `common_type_t<invoke_result_t<Ts>...>` but I don't have the lambdas' arguments, so `invoke_result<Ts..>>::type` fails there.

What am I missing?

Comment: `decltype(declval<Ts>())` is a type of lamba; you might want to do `decltype(declval<Ts>()())`. But it won't work. Suppose one lambda is `[](auto arg) { return arg; }`. Which type should  `test()` have? You can't decide without a `variant` object.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!
If that's the only given lambda I agree that it won't work, but if there is at least one inferrable return type the others need to match (which is my current case).
Unfortunately `decltype(declval<Ts>()())` didn't work as well, even when all lambdas have an inferrable return type.

Comment: `()()` is for parameter-less lamda, you need to pass one parameter inside second `()`. I'll play with it now and if I come up with something meaningful, I'll write an answer.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right!
This worked: `common_type_t<decltype(declval<Ts>()({}))...>`
Thanks!

Comment: Though the default initializer list then fails if one lambda is `[](auto arg) {...}`

Answer (score 2):

This problem has no general solution, because if one of the lambdas is generic, e.g.

```
[](auto arg) { return arg; }
```

then there is no way to deduce the return type without `std::variant` object.

However, we can try to deduce common type from those lambdas that have a non-template `operator()`. The solution for this special case follows.

First make a trait that deduces the return type of a lambda, or returns `empty` if deduction fails:

```
struct empty {};

template<typename Ret, typename Fn, typename Arg>
Ret return_type(Ret(Fn::*)(Arg));

template<typename Ret, typename Fn, typename Arg>
Ret return_type(Ret(Fn::*)(Arg) const);

template<typename Fn>
auto return_type(Fn) -> decltype(return_type(&Fn::operator()));

empty return_type(...);
```

Then tweak `std::common_type`:

```
template<>
struct std::common_type<empty, empty> {
    using type = empty;
};

template<typename T>
struct std::common_type<T, empty> {
    using type = T;
};

template<typename T>
struct std::common_type<empty, T> {
    using type = T;
};
```

And finally put all this together:

```
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... {
    using Ts::operator()...; 
    static auto test() ->
        std::common_type_t<decltype(return_type(std::declval<Ts>()))...>;
};
```

Example:

```
auto fn = overloaded {
    [](auto arg)    { },
    [](int arg)     { return 0;  },
    [](std::string) { return 1.; }
};

static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(fn.test()), double>);
```

If no type can be deduced, the return type of `test()` will be `empty`:

```
auto fn = overloaded {
    [](auto arg) { }
};

static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(fn.test()), empty>);
```